# What is the difference between pandas assign() function and apply() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning data exploration in Python. While practising the `pandas` library, I saw two functions named `df.assign()` and `df.apply()`. The definition of both functions looked very similar. Can you please explain to me these two functions and their unique use cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference concerns whether you wish to *modify* an existing frame, or *create a new frame* while maintaining the original frame as it was.

In particular, `DataFrame.assign` returns you a *new* object that has a copy of the original data with the requested changes, the original frame *remains unchanged*.

For example:

```
df = DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11), 'B': np.random.randn(10)})
```

If you wish to create a new frame in which `A` is everywhere `1` without destroying `df`, you could use `.assign`

```
new_df = df.assign(A=1)
```

Although `.apply` is not intended to be used to modify a dataframe, there is no guarantee that applying the function will not change the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

- **`assign()`** function ([ref1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-assign/), [ref2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html))

> *assign() method assign new columns to a DataFrame, returning a new object (a copy) with the new columns added to the original ones. Existing columns that are re-assigned will be overwritten.*

- **`apply()`** function ([ref1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-apply/), [ref2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html))

> *Apply a function along an axis of the DataFrame. apply() allow the users to pass a function and apply it on every single value of the Pandas series.*